# Haskell programing (GHC 8.8.2) Trim the third element in a list

Tags: haskell

So the function should receives a list of items that at most appear once in that list, and eliminates every third item from that list, for example if the input is[‘a’..‘z’]then the output must be"abdeghjkmnpqstvwyz".

So for my code, I did something like this

```
trimThird :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
trimThird [] = []
trimThird (x:y:z:xs) =  x:y: trimThird xs
```

It true when trimThrid [1..6] => [1,2,4,5] but It will got an error when the list is [1..7]

I am not sure how to add a condition to make it run without any problem, please help me

Comment: The issue is that none of the patterns match lists of length 1 or 2. Think about what you want the function to do in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that besides an empty list, and a list with at least three elements, there are two extra cases: a list with one element, and a list with two elements. Since you recurse on the rest of the list, eventually the list to process will be shorter and shorter, and it is possible that in the end, it will not be an empty list.

You can just here consider two case: (1) a list with at least three elements, and (2) all other lists. For the latter we simply return the list. For example:

```
trimThird :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
trimThird (x:y:z:xs) =  x : y : trimThird xs 
trimThird l = l
```

Note that the `Eq a` type constraint is *not* necessary here, so we can generalize the function to:

```
trimThird :: [a] -> [a]
trimThird (x:y:z:xs) =  x : y : trimThird xs 
trimThird l = l
```